# How to build a solution with multiple build configuration (debug, release) in Azure DevOps build definiton

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-definition

Is something like this possible, to build the solution with two configurations at the same time?

[image: ?]

[image]

Comment: Why do you want that? What do you want to do?

Comment: It was asked in an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Multiplier varaibale has to be supplied without the $ and parenthesis ()

"Under the agent job of the assigned task, on the Parallelism tab, select Multi-configuration and specify the Multipliers separated by commas. For example: BuildConfiguration, BuildPlatform"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-build-multiple-configurations-for-multiple-platforms

Comment: When you don't use a variable you don't need `$()` but if you store the `BuildConfiguration, BuildPlatform` in a variable you can put it in the multi-configuration with a variable format `$()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need go to the Agent Job options -> Parallelism -> Multi-configuration:

[image]

In the build task you put the same variable in the build configuration.

Now the build will be executed twice, one with release configuration and one with debug.

Comment: I did the above changes, still i see this "The specified solution configuration "release,debug|any cpu" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties"

Comment: can you share your build task?

Comment: Added build task screenshot in the question

Comment: did you add the variable to the multipliers?

Comment: Yes, i did.  The $(BuildConfiguration)

Answer (score 1):

Multipliers in the multi-configuration build should not be a variable. It should be `buildConfiguration` [rather than `$(buildConfiguration)`]and this can be defined as the variable in the variable section with different configurations.

```
buildConfiguration = Debug, Release
```